# PDO Split Records in Half

Tags: php, mysql, zurb-foundation

I have been struggling trying to find a way to split the records I have into two columns using a prepared statement and was wondering if any could provide assistance

[Split Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032758/split-records-into-two-columns)

```
<?PHP
$DB_NAME = '';
$DB_HOST = '';
$DB_USER = '';
$DB_PASS = '';

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` ORDER BY _ID ASC"; // Split in half here
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute();   

    echo '  <div class="row">' . "\n";  // Display 1st half here
    echo '      <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
    echo '          <div class="panel">' . "\n";
    while ($row = $prep->fetch()) {
        echo '                  <div class="row">' . "\n";
        echo '                      <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
        echo '                  <b><a href="results.php?id=' . $row['_ID'] . '">' . $row['CODE_NAME'] . '</a></b><br/><br/>' . "\n";
        $timestamp = strtotime($row['CODE_TIMESTAMP']);
        echo '                          Date: ' . date("M d, Y h:m:s A", $timestamp).'<br/><br/>' . "\n";
        echo '                      </div>' . "\n";
        echo '                  </div>' . '<br/>' . "\n";
    }

    $db = null;
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo    '<div class="panel">';
    echo        'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo    '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '          </div>' . "\n";
echo '      </div>' . "\n";
echo '  </div>' . "\n";


 // Create a 2nd column here to display second half
?>
```

I would like to correctly calculate the total number of records and then split it in half and display on half in one column and the other in another which I have figured out I just can't seem to get the records split and then displayed

Comment: If you are lucky, `$prep->rowCount` will give you the correct value, but it will not be portable: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thanks that did give me the correct number and I can do $count = $prep->rowCount()/2 to split it in half now I just have to return the counted records only thanks for the point in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by doing the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<?php $title = 'ALL'; $page = 'all';include 'includes/header.php';?>

<body>

<?php include 'includes/nav.php'; ?>

<div class="row">

<div class="small-6 small columns">
<?php
$DB_NAME = '';
$DB_HOST = '';
$DB_USER = '';
$DB_PASS = '';

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $query = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` ORDER BY _ID ASC";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute();
    $count = $prep->rowCount();
    $half = round($count/2);

    $dsn2 = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
    $db2 = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` ORDER BY _ID ASC Limit " . $half;
    $prep2 = $db2->prepare($query2);
    $prep2->execute();



    echo '  <div class="row">' . "\n";
    echo '      <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
    echo '          <div class="panel">' . "\n";
    while ($row = $prep2->fetch()) {
        echo '                  <div class="row">' . "\n";
        echo '                      <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
        echo '                  <b><a href="results.php?id=' . $row['_ID'] . '">' . $row['CODE_NAME'] . '</a></b><br/><br/>' . "\n";
        $timestamp = strtotime($row['CODE_TIMESTAMP']);
        echo '                          Date: ' . date("M d, Y h:m:s A", $timestamp).'<br/><br/>' . "\n";
        echo '                      </div>' . "\n";
        echo '                  </div>' . '<br/>' . "\n";
    }

    $db = null;
    }


catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo    '<div class="panel">';
    echo        'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo    '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '          </div>' . "\n";
echo '      </div>' . "\n";
echo '  </div>' . "\n";
?>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="small-6 small columns">
<?php
$DB_NAME = '';
 $DB_HOST = '';
$DB_USER = '';
 $DB_PASS = '';

try {

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $query = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` ORDER BY _ID ASC";
     $prep = $db->prepare($query);
     $prep->execute();
    $count = $prep->rowCount();
    $half = round($count/2);

    $dsn2 = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
     $db2 = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` ORDER BY _ID ASC Limit " . $half . ',' . $half;
    $prep2 = $db2->prepare($query2);
    $prep2->execute();

    /*
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `snippets` ORDER BY _ID ASC LIMIT 20,19";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute();
    */
    echo '  <div class="row">' . "\n";
    echo '      <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
    echo '          <div class="panel">' . "\n";
    while ($row = $prep2->fetch()) {
        echo '                  <div class="row">' . "\n";
        echo '                      <div class="large-12 columns">' . "\n";
        echo '                  <b><a href="results.php?id=' . $row['_ID'] . '">' . $row['CODE_NAME'] . '</a></b><br/><br/>' . "\n";
        $timestamp = strtotime($row['CODE_TIMESTAMP']);
        echo '                          Date: ' . date("M d, Y h:m:s A", $timestamp).'<br/><br/>' . "\n";
        echo '                      </div>' . "\n";
        echo '                  </div>' . '<br/>' . "\n";
    }

    $db = null;
    }


catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo    '<div class="panel">';
    echo        'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo    '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '          </div>' . "\n";
echo '      </div>' . "\n";
echo '  </div>' . "\n";
      ?>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>

   <?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
 </body>
```